# NodeMCU ESP8226 wdt reset rst cause:4 boot mode:(1,0)

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I'm trying to simply connect my NodeMCU ESP8226 to my WiFi. I'm running the following code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
// WiFi Settings 
char ssid[] = "wifinetwork";
char pass[] = "admin";

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.disconnect();

  Serial.println("================= S T AR T I N G ==============");
  WiFi.begin(ssid,pass);

  while(!(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)){
    Serial.print("...");

  }
  Serial.println("==== I AM CONNECTED TO THE WIFI ==== ");
  Serial.println("Your IP is: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop(){


}
```

When I run this, I'm promted with the following:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,0)

wdt reset
```

Now, I've tried adding delays pretty much everywhere, installing drivers again and restarting my PC, unplugging, replugging, nothing fixes this. My NodeMCU is connected directly to my USB Port, which apperently shouldn't be an issue.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You should also see a lot of "..." on the console.

This code

```
while(!(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)){
  Serial.print("...");
}
```

is the culprit. In this loop you're completely hogging the CPU and no other components (e.g. WiFi stack) have a chance to run. That's why the watchdog barks and kills it (`wdt reset`).

Comment: So, how would I fix this, simply remove it?

Comment: I now have the following [code](https://pastebin.com/HkwtH7ph) where I then get the error:
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,0)

wdt reset
@Marcel Stör

Comment: First hit on big G for "arduino esp8266 connect to wifi" is http://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/readme.html